# How to create a wrapper to distinguish between 2 or more standalone web service applications

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, soap, wrapper

I have 2 projects in my Eclipse which are actually two standalone webservice(publishes SOAP) applications. Usually I will create 2 JAR files from the 2 projects and I used to run to publish the services. Both applications have the same methods.
Now I have to provide a wrapper on top of those two services provided with a variable to distinguish between the services.

If I try to access a method by passing a variable it should call the appropriate class's implementation.

in the below example, I'm passing animal as an integer. if the animal is 1 Cat class method should be called, if 2 then Dog class method has to respond.

```
Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper();
wrap.makeNoise(int animal);   // 1=Bow-Bow, 2=Meow-Meow
```

Below are the two different Webservice application publishing SOAP

```
class Cat(){
 public void makeNoise(){
  System.out.println("Meow-Meow");
 }
}
```

Cat.java

```
class Dog(){
 public void makeNoise(){
  System.out.println("Bow-Bow");
 }
}
```

Dog.java

Please suggest me how to implement this requirement

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using Strategy pattern ? 
For example you could declare an Interface with void method to start a service.
Next you implement that interface in wrappers and each of them would start different web service and finally you could use some sort of switch or if operators to select (using int) which reference you should cast to an interface reference. Just next after the if/switch operation you could just use that interface method to start the selected service. For example:

public class Test1 {

```
public interface IWebserviceWrapper {

    void startWebservice();
}

public class Cat implements IWebserviceWrapper {

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Meow-Meow");
    }

    @Override
    public void startWebservice() {
        this.makeNoise();

    }
}

public class Dog implements IWebserviceWrapper {

    public void makeNoiseORAnythingElse() {
        System.out.println("Bow-Bow");
    }

    @Override
    public void startWebservice() {
        this.makeNoiseORAnythingElse();
    }

}

public Test1() {

}

public IWebserviceWrapper chooseAnimal(int chosenParam) {
    switch (chosenParam) {
        case 1:
            return new Dog();
        case 2:
            return new Cat();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 example = new Test1();
    int chosenService = 2;
    IWebserviceWrapper service = example.chooseAnimal(chosenService);
    service.startWebservice();
}
```

}

I hope this will help you. There is much more on the topic, so you should probably try to read more about design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Having `switch` or `if else` statement is always a threat to OCP principle of SOLID principles . Hence as @Grzegor Mandela said you can have a common interface by which the client classes can call the required classes ,by the process of dynamic binding which is the core concept of Invetsion Of Control  pattern.

This way of having an adapter for a set of underlying classes also has some similarities as Adapter pattern.

Then you can have one of the factory patterns, like simple factory where you just move your logic of creating objects in to seperate classes , or Abstract Factory pattern in which seperate classes can be created for instatiating each classes object .

Using reflection to create objects by just passing the name of webservice we want can make the code more extensible.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the factory pattern

```
public class ServiceFactory {
    public Service createService(int type) {
        return type == 1 ? new Dog() : new Cat();
    }
}
```

It's a totally valid place to have conditional logic around object instantiation. Also, get rid of the "wrapper" term. It doesn't apply here because you aren't using decorators at any point. You may want to use the term "client" because it sounds like you are acting as the client to several web services.